# How to get form id with jqBootstrapValidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, contact-form

I'm using several forms on my page. So I need to know what form was filled.
I see the solution of problem in getting id of form and sending it in mail.

I use jqBootstrapValidation  and code from this [tutorial](http://myprogrammingblog.com/2013/08/27/how-to-make-a-contact-form-with-bootstrap-3-jqueryphphtml5jqbootstrapvalidation/).

I tried to use this:

```
 var form_id = $(this).parents("form").attr("id");
```

but form_id is undefined.

Please help.

Comment: Use `closest()` instead of `parents()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of tutorial link, you should add your _complete_ and _relevant_ code in question.

Comment: From the `tutorial` you showed there isn't any `id` attached to `form`!! Are you really adding `id` for the `form` apart from tutorial's code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
var form_id = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
```